# Himotoki vs Swift Codable

Tags: json, swift4, decode, codable

I have a project in which I use the Himotoki library to encode and decode JSON. Now, Swift 4 offers the Codable protocol. Should I switch to it or is there some features that Himotoki provides that cannot be implemented with Codable ?

Comment: I have never used Himotoki, but find the question interesting. Would you mind adding a couple of functionalities that Himotoki provides that you benefit from? I am happy user of `Codable`, so I'd like to see what the library does.

Comment: well actually it is a legacy issue. The Himotoki framework was used when the codable protocol was not provided in swift. When migrating to swift 4, a conflict between the codable protocol from Himotoki and from Foundation appeared. So now, I am considering to remove Himotoki. But since it is used evrywhere in my project. I just want to check that I won't introduce some regression.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

It depends on how well you are able to use the `Codable` features that Himotoki doesn't have, namely

- Encoding

  Is there a possibility that you want to encode your models at some point in the future?
- Auto generated `Codable` implementations

  Do your models have non-property-list type properties?
- Decode/encode from not just JSON

  Do you need to decode other types of data representation e.g. binary in the future?

Also, `Decoder` accepts `Data` instances as input whereas you can use `Dictionary` or `Data`for Himotoki. So if getting dictionaries is more convenient for you, `Codable` will be a little less convenient as you need to convert that to `Data`.

Last but not least, `Codable` is widely known in the community. Using Himotoki might make it harder for others to understand the code, especially with those custom operators. Himotoki only has ~700 stars at the moment. Compare this to ObjectMapper which has thousands. Obviously this isn't a problem if your code is private.

Comment: Thanks. I am using himotoki to decode JSon into struct everywhere in my project. I had to add encode func to create Dictonaries that I use with Alamofire to send data. By the way Alamofire does not provide a support for handling Codable responses yet.

Comment: The question is the same with ObjectMapper. Why using it since you can simply manage objects with the Codable protocol and avoid relying on external frameworks.

Comment: Just by looking at README of Himotoki it doesn’t seem to continue support for encoding. If using Alamofire with Codable is really inconvenient, and if your models’ `Codable` implementation cannot be auto generated, then I suggest ObjectMapper because it can directly encode to dictionary. The final decision is on you. I have given you some questions to think about.